# Apport reports packages to be outdated when they are up-to-date

Tags: upgrade, crash, bug-reporting, apport

I recently tried to report a crash using Apport to Launchpad using:

```
sudo apport-cli --crash-file=/var/crash/_usr_bin_software-properties-gtk.0.crash
```

However was met with the following message after telling it to send the report:

```
The problem cannot be reported:

You have some obsolete package versions installed. Please upgrade the following packages and check if the problem still occurs:

dbus, isc-dhcp-client, isc-dhcp-common, krb5-locales, libdbus-1-3, libglib2.0-0, libglib2.0-data, libgssapi-krb5-2, libk5crypto3, libkrb5-3, libkrb5support0, unattended-upgrades
```

But as far as I am aware, all of those packages are up-to-date, at least as up-to-date as they can be given the package versions in the stable repositories. I have tried running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and it says my system is up-to-date.

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 with GNOME 3.22, it is important that I report this crash so I am wondering what to do? Why does it think that they are obsolete? Are they in some way? If so, what are my options? Is there any way to bypass this check in Apport?

**Information Update:**

As requested in the comments, here is the notice in the `.crash` file:

```
Title: software-properties-gtk crashed with SIGSEGV
UnreportableReason:
 You have some obsolete package versions installed. Please upgrade the following packages and check if the problem still occurs:

 dbus, isc-dhcp-client, isc-dhcp-common, krb5-locales, libdbus-1-3, libglib2.0-0, libglib2.0-data, libgssapi-krb5-2, libk5crypto3, libkrb5-3, libkrb5support0, unattended-upgrades
UpgradeStatus: Upgraded to yakkety on 2016-10-19 (61 days ago)
_MarkForUpload: True
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50415/discussion-between-kaz-wolfe-and-paranoid-panda).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely happened because Apport detected older packages at the time of the crash, and (as such) is trying to ignore the report as possibly invalid.

You can ignore the "outdated" warning by using the `APPORT_IGNORE_OBSOLETE_PACKAGES` environment variable.

Simply prepend your command with the following to force Apport to report anyways.

```
APPORT_IGNORE_OBSOLETE_PACKAGES=1 <your_command>
```

If that fails to work (as per [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/427810)), stripping out the `UnreportableReason` section of the report should allow for it to go through.

Comment: I tried that but the error is still there and not letting me pass.